# ps error /proc must be mounted - but works as root

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, proc

This is an OpenVZ VPS box. For example:

```
$ ps
Error: /proc must be mounted
  To mount /proc at boot you need an /etc/fstab line like:
  /proc   /proc   proc    defaults
 In the meantime, run "mount /proc /proc -t proc"

$ sudo ps
[sudo] password for ....:
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4699 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo
 4700 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Its only started recently (possibly since an `apt-get upgrade`).  I also ran `locale-gen` recently, but I don't see how that would affect things.

```
uname -a
Linux stormvz1 2.6.32-042stab072.10 #1 SMP Wed Jan 16 18:54:05 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
```

UPDATED

Tried changing /proc, but did not help:

```
$ ls -ld /proc
dr-xr-xr-x 98 root root 0 Apr  9 20:11 /proc
$ sudo chmod 755 /proc
[sudo] password for ....:
$ ls -ld /proc
drwxr-xr-x 98 root root 0 Apr  9 20:11 /proc
$ ps
Error: /proc must be mounted
```

Have also done several reboots - largely seems ok, but just this 'glitch'

proc is in fstab, but seems ok:

```
grep proc /etc/fstab
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
```

The files in `/proc` look like this - which seem ok to my untrained eye:

```
$ sudo ls -la /proc
[sudo] password for kimptoc:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 105 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root     root     4096 Mar  4 19:18 ..
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 1
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 108
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr 11 02:06 12337
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 139
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 140
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 173
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 2
dr-xr-xr-x   6 www-data www-data    0 Apr  9 21:02 2184
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 251
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 285
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 3
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr 11 07:20 30162
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 30784
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr 11 07:20 30825
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr 11 07:20 30827
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr 11 07:20 30831
dr-xr-xr-x   6 kimptoc  kimptoc     0 Apr 11 07:20 30844
dr-xr-xr-x   6 kimptoc  kimptoc     0 Apr 11 07:20 30845
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     kimptoc     0 Apr 11 07:20 30907
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 30908
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 315
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 317
dr-xr-xr-x   6 syslog   syslog      0 Apr  9 20:11 401
dr-xr-xr-x   6 bind     bind        0 Apr  9 20:11 419
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 527
dr-xr-xr-x   6 postfix  postfix     0 Apr  9 20:11 531
dr-xr-xr-x   6 mongodb  nogroup     0 Apr  9 22:10 5372
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 557
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 559
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 663
dr-xr-xr-x   6 www-data www-data    0 Apr  9 20:11 667
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 86
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 cgroups
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 cmdline
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 cpuinfo
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 devices
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 fairsched
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 fairsched2
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 filesystems
dr-xr-xr--   3 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 fs
-r--------   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 kmsg
-r--r--r--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 loadavg
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 locks
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 meminfo
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 modules
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root       11 Apr 11 07:20 mounts -> self/mounts
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root        8 Apr 11 07:20 net -> self/net
-r--r--r--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 partitions
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root       64 Apr  9 20:11 self -> 30908
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 stat
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 swaps
dr-xr-xr-x   1 root     root        0 Apr  9 20:11 sys
--wx--x---   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 sysrq-trigger
dr-xr-xr--   2 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 sysvipc
-r-xr-x---   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 uptime
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 user_beancounters
-r--r--r--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 version
-r-xr-xr--   1 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 vmstat
dr-xr-x---   3 root     root        0 Apr 11 07:20 vz
```

UPDATE

I rebuilt the VPS in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you, or perhaps a buggy script running as root, changed the permissions of `/proc`. Check them: `ls -ld /proc`

This should fix it:

```
sudo chmod 755 /proc
```

If this isn't enough, a reboot is probably easiest. You may be able to limp on.

Check if other files in `/proc` are affected as well: `ls -l /proc`. Depending on which files were affected, the following may be enough of a fix (this isn't a complete list, only the most important).

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /proc/[a-z]*
find /proc -type d -exec sudo chmod +x {} +
sudo chmod 600 /proc/kcore /proc/kmsg /proc/kpagecount /proc/kpageflags /proc/vmallocinfo
sudo chmod 200 /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Make sure that you don't have a line for `/proc` in `/etc/fstab` (it's normally not needed because the startup script mount it early in the boot process anyway), or if you do, it contains only the following (and optionally `0 0` at the end):

```
proc  /proc  proc  defaults
```

If your `fstab` is correct and a reboot doesn't fix everything, you have a bigger problem. Do post at least the output of `sudo ls -la /proc` and `uname -a`.

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
strace ps aux | wc -l
```

I find :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today. It turned out to be an incomplete apparmor profile for ps. Using `sudo aa-logprof` I got this new profile in /etc/apparmor.d/, which restored ps to its normal:

```
# Last Modified: Thu Mar 14 10:49:01 2019
#include <tunables/global>

/bin/ps {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/consoles>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/totem>

  capability sys_ptrace,

  /bin/ps mr,
  /etc/ld.so.preload r,
  /proc/*/cmdline r,
  /proc/*/stat r,
  /proc/*/status r,
  /proc/*/wchan r,
  /proc/filesystems r,
  /proc/meminfo r,
  /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease r,
  /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max r,
  /proc/tty/drivers r,
  /proc/uptime r,

}
```

Don't forget to:

- Backup your old profile before trying a new one.
- Restart apparmor with `sudo service apparmor restart` or `/etc/init.d apparmor restart` after making any changes.

Comment: Where is the profile located, one would need to know this to back it up, please add this information to your answer.

Comment: @mook765 It's done!